# ng-click not working on CPANEL/local but works using live server (vscode)

Tags: angularjs

I am currently doing an assignment and came across this problem. My code works fine with live server but when uploaded it to CPANEL, my (I'm assuming) ng-click is not firing like it does on live server.

**ng-app & ng-controller**

```
<body class="bg-gray-200"  ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
```

**ng-click**

```
<button class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-3 py-1 text-xs rounded" ng-click="home()">Home</button>
  <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-3 py-1 text-xs rounded" ng-click="ajaxjson()">AJAX/JSON</button>
  <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-3 py-1 text-xs rounded" ng-click="contact()">Contact</button>
```

**js file**

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)
{
  $scope.home = function()
  {
    $(".content").html
    (
      `<h1 class="text-lg font-medium">Home</h1>
      <p class="text-sm">
        Welcome to Andy's Assignment 3! Click a button on the top or one of the quick links to the left!
      </p>`
    );
  }

  $scope.contact = function()
  {
    $(".content").html
    (
      `<h1 class="text-lg font-medium">Contact</h1>
      <p class="text-sm">
        Email: myemail@school.com
      </p>`
    );
  }
});
```

When I click the on the content button, the html isnt getting overridden. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Out of all the things that I tried, it was the file path. It worked perfectly with live server but, I had to remove a / from my js file path.